# How to compare json object key with a day of the week

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So i have an array with dates:

```
 var aryDates = ["2020-07-27", "2020-07-29", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-07", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-03"]
```

And i have this three other arrays that i use to assign in my json:

```
var activities = ["Study", "Go to the gym"]
var times = ["11:30 - 12:30", "18:30 - 19:00"]
var weeks = ["monday", "wednesday"]
```

My objective is to create an JSON like this:

```
{
  2020-07-27: [{ ----> monday
  name: "Study",
  time: "11:30 - 12:30",
  week: "monday"
}],
  2020-07-29: [{ ----> wednesday
  name: "Go to the gym",
  time: "18:30 - 19:00",
  week: "wednesday"
}],
  2020-08-01: [{ ----> saturday
  name: "undefined",
  time: "undefined",
  week: "undefined"
}],
  2020-08-03: [{ ----> monday
  name: "Study",
  time: "11:30 - 12:30",
  week: "monday"
}],
 2020-08-05: [{ ----> wednesday
  name: "Go to the gym",
  time: "18:30 - 19:00",
  week: "wednesday"
}],
  2020-08-07: [{ ----> friday
  name: "undefined",
  time: "undefined",
  week: "undefined"
}],
}
```

The activities that have the **'week' === monday** goes to the dates that are **monday** such as **2020-07-27**, **2020-08-03**, and so on with the other activities.

Here is what i did so far https://jsfiddle.net/mh3dq45j/6/

I'm able to create the JSON, but i don't know how to assign each activity week with the dates.

Comment: *assign each activity week with the dates.* Dates or days ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping With the dates for example '2020-07-27'. If an activity is on a monday i want to assign this activity with every date of the aryDates array that are mondays. And put them in the JSON as i showed in my question.

Comment: Is there a reason why your values are arrays when you only have one object in them? Can the value fo each date key just be a single object?

Comment: @Nick Parsons  yeah thats something that I dont explain, I'm using this lib https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#agenda and you can have more than one object in a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a `Map` which keeps track of each day in the week. Each key in the map would be a day from `weeks` and would store an object which has the name, time and week for the day.

The `Map` is essentially like an object, and would end up having the following shape:

```
{
  "monday" => {name: "Study", time: "11:30 - 12:30", week: "monday"}
  "wednesday" => {name: "Go to the gym", time: "18:30 - 19:00", week: "wednesday"}
}
```

(Note that this is not valid JS syntax, its just used to represent what the Map would look like, where the string to the left of the `=>` is the key and the object to the right of the `=>` is the value).

You can then also create a helper function called `getDay`, which will convert a date to a day for you.
For example:

```
getDay("2020-07-27") // Outputs: "monday"
```

Then, you can use `.map()` on `aryDates`. For each date string in this array, you can convert it to a day using the helper function.
You can then check the map to see if it contains a key which is this day using `weeksMap.get(<day>)`. If `<day>` is in the map (ie: if `<day>` is either `"monday"` or `"wednesday"` then it will return its associated object value. If it is not in the map, `.get()` will return `undefined`.

Using this idea to our advantage, we can use the [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which will "merge" the key/values from an object into an existing object:

```
{a: 1, ...{a: 0, b: 2}} // Becomes {a: 1, a: 0, b: 0}, Output: {a: 0, b: 2}
{a: 1, ...undefined} // Output: {a: 1}
```

As you can see, if we spread an object, any keys within the object being spread overwrite those in the original object. This way, by using:

```
{name: undefined, time: undefined, week: undefined, ...weeksMap.get(getDay(date))}
```

You will overwrite the name, time and week keys if `weeksMap.get()` returns an object with those keys.

Once we have the object constructed, you can add it to an array `[key, value]`, where `value` is an array with an object `[object]` (as per your desired output). You can then use the `Object.fromEntries()` on an array of key-value pairs `[[key, value], [key2, value2], ...]`, which is what is returned by the `.map()` we wrote.

See example below:

```js
const getDay = date => new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(undefined, {weekday: "long"}).toLowerCase();

const aryDates = ["2020-07-27", "2020-07-29", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-07", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-03"].sort((a, b)=>a.localeCompare(b));

const activities = ["Study", "Go to the gym"]
const times = ["11:30 - 12:30", "18:30 - 19:00"]
const weeks = ["monday", "wednesday"];

const weeksMap = new Map(weeks.map((week, i) => [week, {
  name: activities[i],
  time: times[i],
  week
}]));

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  aryDates.map(date => [date, [{name: undefined, time: undefined, week: undefined, ...weeksMap.get(getDay(date))}]])
);

console.log(res);
```

If you can't support `Object.fromEntries()`, you can consider using a varient with `Object.assign()` and `.map()`:

```js
const getDay = date => new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(undefined, {weekday: "long"}).toLowerCase();

const aryDates = ["2020-07-27", "2020-07-29", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-07", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-03"].sort((a, b)=>a.localeCompare(b));

const activities = ["Study", "Go to the gym"]
const times = ["11:30 - 12:30", "18:30 - 19:00"]
const weeks = ["monday", "wednesday"];

const weeksMap = new Map(weeks.map((week, i) => [week, {
  name: activities[i],
  time: times[i],
  week
}]));

const res = Object.assign({},
  ...aryDates.map(date => ({[date]: [{name: undefined, time: undefined, week: undefined, ...weeksMap.get(getDay(date))}]}))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice one. Was about to post a similar solution.

Comment: @jarwin I added more details to my answer, you can take another look at it and see if the edit helps. I'm not too sure what you mean by "why it shows only undefined in the json". JSON is a string format, used to represent JavaScript objects/data. So it is different from an object (which is what `res` is). A JSON string doesn't have values which are `undefined`, so doing `JSON.stringify()` on an object with undefined values will remove those from the result. You can, however, make your `undefined` a string `"undefined"`, and then use `JSON.stringify()` if that's what you're after.

Comment: @NickParsons Actually i figured out why only appears undefined for me, if you put your clock to the timezone utc-03 you will see that getDay("2020-07-27") output sunday. So i put my timezone to yours and it worked. I fixed for my timezone doing that https://jsfiddle.net/6cqbrf19/ adding one more day

Answer (score 0):

first i'm copying your code in jsfiddle here to debug it

```
var aryDates = ["2020-07-27", "2020-07-29", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-07", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-03"]

 var activities = ["Study", "Go to the gym"]
 var times = ["11:30 - 12:30", "18:30 - 19:00"]
 var weeks = ["monday", "wednesday"]

 const obj = aryDates.map((dates, index) => {
   return ('"' + dates + '":' + "[{" +
     '"name"' + ":" + '"' + activities[index] + '"' + "," +
     '"time"' + ":" + '"' + times[index] + '"' + "," +
     '"week"' + ": " + '"' + weeks[index] + '"' +
     "}]");
 })

 const jsonObj = `{${obj}}`

 console.log(JSON.parse(jsonObj))
```

when you refer to `weeks[index]` the index is the index of the running loop not necessarily related to the week day. in case you want to get the code for week day you can use `Date.getDay()` if you want to support all week days you can use code below

```
     var aryDates = ["2020-07-27", "2020-07-29", "2020-08-01", "2020-08-07", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-03"]

 var activities = [null,"Study",null, "Go to the gym",null,null,null]
 var times = [null,"11:30 - 12:30",null, "18:30 - 19:00",null,null,null]
 var weeks = [null,"monday", null,"wednesday",null,null,null]

 const obj = aryDates.map((dates, index) => {
 var d = new Date(dates);
    var dayCode= d.getDay();
   return ('"' + dates + '":' + "[{" +
     '"name"' + ":" + '"' + activities[dayCode] + '"' + "," +
     '"time"' + ":" + '"' + times[dayCode] + '"' + "," +
     '"week"' + ": " + '"' + weeks[dayCode] + '"' +
     "}]");
 })

 const jsonObj = `{${obj}}`

 console.log(JSON.parse(jsonObj))
```

variable d takes the given time like 2020-07-27 and converts that to javascript date object and d.getDay() return a number related to week day of the given date  0 for sunday up to 6 for saturday and we use this code to detect which activity belongs to which date.